# Check one checkbox to select multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table where I'd like to be able to check one checkbox in the header to select all checkboxes in that table. This should normally be a quite straightforward thing, but it is simply not working here. When I run the sample code at JSfiddle it works. When running it in my development environment and checking the top box, if I put alert() it will alert, but still not check the rest of the checkboxes. Any ideas why?

```
[JS fiddle][1]

http://jsfiddle.net/pkvLqe1d/
```

And here is the code in my development environment:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
<form id="selectContent" method="post" class="grow">
<table class="static" style="width:1000px;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
        <b>Id</b>
        </th>
        <th>
        <b>Name</b>
        </th>
        <th>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></label>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<td>$b->id</td>";
        echo "<td>$b->name</td>"; 
        echo "<td><label><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='".trim($b->id)."' class='round'></label></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</form>


</div>

<script>
//Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {

        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {

        this.checked = true;

        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, when I run your fiddle, it works, just like you say.  That means there is something else wrong, and you haven't shown us your real code.  That'll make it hard to help you.  (One of the requirements of SO is a "minimal working example" that illustrates the problem.  May we please see that?)

Comment: And here is a JSfiddle where it is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/04btkoL5/

Comment: When I run that in the Firebug debugger, it says, "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list."  (The line number isn't useful because of the way JSFiddle works.)  What happens when you run it with a debugger?

Comment: @BobBrown I've updated JSfiddle now based on this, and now it works there, but still not in my development environment. Strange :/

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but for us to help you, we've got to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, so after looking closer at this I can see the checkboxes in fact do get selected upon posting the form. However, they do not physically get marked for some reason. Could this rather be a CSS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using ezmark checkboxes, the solution was to add .change() at the end of the script as shown below. This will simply set the checked status of the retrieved checkboxes equal to that of our recently modified 'master' checkbox:

```
$('#select-all').click(function() {
$(':checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked).change();
});
```